Trigger (after delete) restricts from deleting records
Can you help me figure out what is the issue with the following trigger method?
(see error below; when to delete employee with inactive trigger, record is deleted)
This trigger:
trigger EmployeeTrigger on Employee__c (before delete, after delete) {   
    if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete)
        EmployeeTriggerHandler.afterDelete(Trigger.old);
}     

Is calling this method:
public class EmployeeTriggerHandler {
    
    //After employee is deleted, update 'Left Employee Count' on Account
    public static void afterDelete(List<Employee__c> oldList){
        List<Account> accToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for (Employee__c e : oldList){
            if (e.Account__c != null){
                e.Account__r.Left_Employee_Count__c = [SELECT count() FROM Employee__c WHERE Account__c =: e.Account__c];
                accToUpdate.add(e.Account__r);
            }
        }
        update accToUpdate;
    }
}

When I delete an employee record (tried via UI), it ends with this error:

There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to
edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your
administrator for help.


You didn't provide the Account Id, nor did you query it, so your trigger is trying to call update without an Id.
public class EmployeeTriggerHandler {    
    //After employee is deleted, update 'Left Employee Count' on Account
    public static void afterDelete(List<Employee__c> oldList){
        // Accounts to update, deduplicated by Id
        Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
        // Record counts
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> recordCounts = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>();
        // Aggregate the account Id values
        for(Employee__c record: oldList) {
            accounts.put(record.Account__c, new Account(Id=record.Account__c));
        }
        // Ignore null values (more efficient than if)
        accounts.remove(null);
        // Get the record counts all at once
        recordCounts.putAll([SELECT Account__c Id, COUNT(Id) recordCount FROM Employee__c WHERE Account__c = :accounts.keySet() GROUP BY Account__c]);
        // For each account, get the record count, or default to 0 (optional)
        for(Account record: accounts.values()) {
            record.Left_Employee_Count__c = (Integer) recordCounts.get(record.Id)?.get('recordCount') ?? 0;
        }
        // update the records
        update account.values();
    }
}

Edit: Additional notes.
recordCounts.putAll works with a query when there is a field called Id (in this case, an alias, also note it is case-sensitive), that automatically maps the records instead of a manual for loop.
?. is the Safe Navigation Operator. It returns null instead of throwing a null pointer exception when a value is null. This would happen if there are no Employee records associated with the Account Id.
?? is the Null Coalescing Operator. If the value on the left is null, then the value on the right is used as a default value. This avoids an additional if statement. Note that the return type for each side must be the same, so we use the (Integer) to cast the recordCount from an Object to an Integer.

I'd add an explanation about why the recordCounts.putAll works with the alias for Account__c to Id - it's a really clever dodge that I recall you showing before. It warrants a more descriptive comment.

@PhilW Fair enough. I added some more detail.

@sfdcfox, can you please explain this bit (the spaces between fields - what is that representing?):
SELECT Account__c Id, COUNT(Id) recordCount

@Mywen This is the Alias Notation. It allows you to refer to a field by a different name. We use this to get readable names instead of expr0, expr1, etc that aggregate queries alias to by default, and Id allows the map to be populated automatically, as mentioned in the answer.

Thanks a lot for all the additional details! I'll need to spend some more time trying each concept separately so it makes better sense to me.

@sfdcfox "accounts.remove(null);" will remove a null value (if there is one), or can there be multiple nulls? (I'm thinking Map -> unique keys -> only one null possible)

@Mywen You are correct. The map's keys are in a Set, which only stores unique values. Null is a unique value from all other values, so it can be stored in the map at most once. This is a trick I use to avoid an if statement inside a loop, since it's easier code coverage and performs faster in most cases.

I see, thanks @sfdcfox.
Just one more question: Do I understand correctly that if "put" or "putAll" to a map from a query, then there needs to be a field called "Id" in that query, and then the map uses that field as a key? Otherwise, it wouldn't work?

@Mywen For add, you can use whatever field you want. For putAll using sObject records, it always needs the Id. For normal queries, this is automatically included in Apex, but for AggregateResult queries, you must alias a field as Id to use putAll.

I see, thank you!

Setting aside that you should probably be using the DLRS Tool instead of making your own rollup code...
Trigger context variables do not contain any related data, so e.Account__r is going to be null (or perhaps in this case, an empty SObject).
If e.Account__r is an empty SObject, then it won't have an Id. When you go to update the Accounts, you're probably running into an error (no id specified for update) which then gets turned into a generic error message in the UI.
It's also possible that you're getting an error when you try to assign the result of the query with aggregate operations (which returns a List<AggregateResult>) to a single field.
The query inside of your loop is also problematic, and it should be brought outside of the loop.
If you're going to be doing this yourself, it should look something like (pseudocode):
mymethod(list of employees) {
    // to pull the query outside of the loop, first gather the Ids
    for loop over employees
        gather Account__c in a list or set

    // Then you can query
    // you can alias fields (which is what I've done with the count of employee ids) to
    //   make things more explicit and easier to read
    for(AggregateResult ar : [SELECT Account__c, COUNT(Id) employeeCount FROM Employee__c WHERE <conditions> GROUP BY Account__c]) {
        // Use Account__c to set the id of a new Account instance
        accountList.add(new Account(
            // working with AggregateResult means you'll end up doing a lot of typecasting
            // Id can be set in SObject constructors
            Id = (Id)ar.get('Account__c'),
            Count = (Integer)ar.get('employeeCount')
       ));
    }

    dml update
}

The "Set the Id in the SObject constructor" bit is especially helpful. That tip alone would be the minimal change required to get your code to work.
Substituting
e.Account__r.Left_Employee_Count__c = <query>
accToUpdate.add(e.Account__r);

for
accToUpdate.add(new Account(
    Id = e.Account__c,
    Left_Employee_Count__c = <query with a few tweaks>
));

would do it since you're no longer relying on related data (just the Account__c field that is part of the Employee__c record directly).
Though this would also fail if you tried to delete multiple Employees under the same Account at the same time ("duplicate id in list" when you perform the dml). Using a map keyed on the account id instead of a list would be one way to resolve that.
But again, queries inside of loops are bad 99.999% of the time, and your case is definitely not in the 0.0001%. Pull the query outside of the loop.

Thanks a lot, Derek!
I appreciate you were making it a bit more simple for me. I wish there were multiple "best answers" to choose since really both answers complemented so well. Also, thanks for the DLRS tool - I'll keep that in my notes as well!
